# Using Recursion to Solve a Maze in java

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I attempted this problem and for some reason its not coming out correct. Given an array of strings, find how many possible solutions exist to the maze where the strings consist of one "R" (the rat), one "C" (the cheese), multiple "X's (blocks that cannot be passed through), and "."'s (possible pathways). The task is to find the number of possible routes the rat can take to get to the cheese without ever increasing the (Euclidean) distance between itself and the cheese at any point on its path. What looks wrong with my code?

```
public class RatRoute { 
private static String[] enc;
private static int count;
private static int[] r;
private static int[] c;

// Test the program
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = {
            ".R...",
            "..X..",
            "....X",
            "X.X.X",
            "...C."};
    int num1 = numRoutes(test);
    System.out.println(num1);   
}

// Set variables, and call recursive function
public static int numRoutes(String[] enc) {
    RatRoute.enc = enc;     
    r = findR(enc);
    c = findC(enc);
    recursiveHelper(r[0], r[1]);
    return count;
}

// Recursive 
public static void recursiveHelper(int x, int y) {

    /*System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (int k = 0; k < enc.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(enc[k]);
    }*/

    if(isBlock(x,y)) {
        return;
    } else if (isBigger(x,y)) {
        return;
    } else if (isCheese(x, y)) {
        count++;
        //System.out.println("Found the Cheese! Path number: " + count);
        //System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    enc[x] = currentPath(x,y);      
    recursiveHelper(x + 1, y);
    recursiveHelper(x, y + 1);
    recursiveHelper(x, y - 1);
    recursiveHelper(x - 1, y);
    enc[x] = returnPath(x,y);

}

// Change the most recently traveled coordinates into a block 
public static String currentPath(int x, int y) {
    char[] Chars = enc[x].toCharArray();
    Chars[y] = 'X';
    String newString = String.valueOf(Chars);
    return newString;       
}

// Turn path already traveled from blocks back into a usable path to travel (undo the currentPath method)
public static String returnPath(int x, int y) {
    char[] Chars = enc[x].toCharArray();
    Chars[y] = '.';
    String newString = String.valueOf(Chars);
    return newString;       
}

// Check if the next movement is into the cheese
public static boolean isCheese(int x, int y) {
    if (enc[x].charAt(y) == 'C') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Check if the next movement is into a block, or outside the given array
public static boolean isBlock(int x, int y) {   
    if (x == -1 || y == -1
            || x >= enc.length || y >= enc[x].length()) {
        return true;
    } else if (enc[x].charAt(y) == 'X') {
        //System.out.println(x + "," + y);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// See if the distance between the rat and the cheese has gotten larger or smaller
public static boolean isBigger(int x, int y) {
    double rx = r[0]; double ry = r[1];
    double cx = c[0]; double cy = c[1];

    double originalDist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rx-cx, 2) + Math.pow(ry-cy, 2));
    double newDist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-cx, 2) + Math.pow(y-cy, 2));

    //System.out.println("Orginal Distance: " + originalDist);
    //System.out.println("New Distance: " + newDist);

    if (newDist > originalDist) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Find the variables for the original position of the rat
public static int[] findR(String[] enc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < enc.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < enc[i].length(); j++) {
            if (enc[i].charAt(j) == 'R') {
                int[] coordinates = {i, j};
                //System.out.println(coordinates[0] + "," + coordinates[1]);
                return coordinates;                 
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
    int[] other = {-1, -1};
    return other;
}

// Find the variables for the original position of the rat
public static int[] findC(String[] enc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < enc.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < enc[i].length(); j++) {
            if (enc[i].charAt(j) == 'C') {
                int[] coordinates = {i, j};
                //System.out.println(coordinates[0] + "," + coordinates[1]);
                return coordinates;                 
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
    int[] other = {-1, -1};
    return other;
}
```

}

Comment: The answer to the particular example in the code would be 3, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from an useful observation:

> [...] without ever increasing the (Euclidean) distance between itself and
>   the cheese at any point on its path.

Basically what it means is that whenever the rat gets closer to the cheese it never goes back to a farther position.

So let's say the rat *x* coordinate is 3 and the cheese *x* coordinate is 5 the rat cannot "go left" (i.e. `x = 2`) because this would cause it to be farther than before form the cheese.

Because of this, a nice way to simple the problem is to find the directions the rat can go. In your example the rat is up-left from the cheese, so it will only be able to move down or right because otherwise it would get farther from the cheese. When the rat *x* matches the cheese *x* it won't be able to move right or left anymore, same goes for the *y*.

With your code, if:

```
r[0] - c[0] = 0 // the rat cannot move on the x any more.
r[1] - c[1] = 0 // the rat cannot move on the y any more.
```

When

```
r[0] - c[0] == 0 && r[1] - c[1] == 0
```

The rat reached the cheese! In this case, we can increment the counter because a successful route was found.

Now let's put this in practice with recursion.
From the code you posted, we start with a given `c` (found with `findC(enc)`) and a given `r` (found with `findR(enc)`)

So the recursive method would look like this:

```
private void findRoutesFrom(int[] r) {
    // what directions can the rat go?
    // if the cheese is on the right of the mouse, xDirection
    // would be +1.
    int xDirection = (int) Math.signum(c[0] - r[0]);
    // if the cheese is below of the mouse, yDirection
    // would be +1.
    int yDirection = (int) Math.signum(c[1] - r[1]);

    // Now, if xDirection is != 0 the rat can attempt to move
    // in that direction, checking if there's not a block
    if(xDirection != 0 && !isBlock(r[0] + xDirection, r[1])) {
        // if it can move in that direction, then use recursion to
        // find all the possible paths form the new position
        findRoutesFrom(new int[]{r[0] + xDirection, r[1]});
    }

    // same goes for yDirection
    if(yDirection != 0 && !isBlock(r[0], r[1] + yDirection)) {
        findRoutesFrom(new int[]{r[0], r[1] + yDirection});
    }

    // if the rat reaches the cheese, increase the successful
    // paths counter
    if(xDirection == 0 && yDirection == 0) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

That's it! Because of the Eculedean distance constraint it is enough to check if the directions are `!= 0` because, when that is false, then the rat cannot move on that direction any more.